# Java android app is unable to connect with bluetooth shutter/VR remote for camera using socket

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, virtual-reality, shutter

I am trying to make an app that is able to read the Bluetooth remote signals whatever data it sends.  I only have a cheap VR remote and a shutter remote with me.
I can get their mac addresses and UUIDs after pairing.

The part with the Bluetooth socket connection keeps crashing.  Is there a better way to do this?

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button b1,b2,b3,b4;
private BluetoothAdapter BA;
private Set<BluetoothDevice>pairedDevices;
ListView lv;
ListView uuidlist;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String message = i.getStringExtra("Info");
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText(message);


    b1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_on);
    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_off);
    b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.list_devices);
    b4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.visible);

    BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    uuidlist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    String uuid = get_uuid_from_paired_devices();

    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.uuid)).setText(uuid);
    final UUID mUUID = UUID.fromString(uuid);
    String mac = get_mac_from_paired_devices();
    mac = mac.replaceAll("[\\[\\](){}]","");
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.mac)).setText(mac);


    //BluetoothDevice remote = BA.getRemoteDevice(mac);
    BluetoothDevice remote;
    BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

    BluetoothSocket socket = null;

    try  {
        mmServerSocket = BA.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("remote", mUUID);
        socket = mmServerSocket.accept();


    }  catch (Exception e) {

    }

    **////////// stuck here with the bluetooth socket**


}

public void on(View v){
    if (!BA.isEnabled()) {
        Intent turnOn = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(turnOn, 1);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Turned on",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void off(View v){
    BA.disable();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Turned off" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


public  void visible(View v){
    Intent getVisible = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
    startActivityForResult(getVisible, 1);
}


public void list(View v){
    pairedDevices = BA.getBondedDevices();

    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices) list.add(bt.getName());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Showing Paired Devices",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    final ArrayAdapter adapter = new  ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);


}

public void unpair(View v) {
    Set<BluetoothDevice> bondedDevices = BA.getBondedDevices();
    try {
        Class<?> btDeviceInstance =  Class.forName(BluetoothDevice.class.getCanonicalName());
        Method removeBondMethod = btDeviceInstance.getMethod("removeBond");

        boolean cleared = false;
        for (BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice : bondedDevices) {
            String mac = bluetoothDevice.getAddress();

            removeBondMethod.invoke(bluetoothDevice);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Cleared Pairing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
            cleared = true;
            break;

        }

        if(!cleared) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Not paired", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }
    } catch (Throwable th) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Error pairing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    }
}

private String get_uuid_from_paired_devices(){  //Get the list UUIDs
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = BA.getBondedDevices();
    String uuid_string = "";
    for (BluetoothDevice device: pairedDevices){

        for (ParcelUuid uuid: device.getUuids()){
            uuid_string = uuid.toString();

        }
    }

    return uuid_string;
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) concept? A lot of people won't even look at your code because they'll have to dig through a bunch of UI code just to find a bug in your Bluetooth code.
First of all, you should probably start by giving us the error message of the exception.

Comment: I labelled where the bluetooth socket command wasnt working.  Anyways. I changed the UUID and MAC address into literals """.  So it no longer crashes but still cant receive any reads.  It does receive the onkeyevents from the remotes in logcat.  There is no more error debugging coding but again no data is received.